# Discord.js V12 Userinfo createdAt / joinedAt undefined

Tags: undefined, discord.js, userinfo

Im new to this and trying learn as i go here but im struggling with this code, im totally confused. iv managed to get everything working (eventually) except from the following issues, .userinfo @randomUser produces all the users details apart from

*date registered 
&
*date joined

removing these lines allow everything else to work fine. Is it also possible to display users roles?

- **ERROR**

  userinfo.registered = moment.gmt(m.guild.members.fetch(user.id).user.createdAt);
                                                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'createdAt' of undefined

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const moment = require("moment");

const bot = new Discord.Client({ disableEveryone: true});

bot.on("ready", () => console.log(`Connected to Discord!`))

bot.on("message", m => {
    let prefix = ".";
    if (m.author.bot || !m.guild) return;
    if (!m.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

if (m.content.startsWith(prefix + "userinfo")) {
    let user = (m.mentions.users.first()) || m.author;
    let member = m.mentions.members.first() || m.member;


    let userinfo = {};
    userinfo.avatar = user.displayAvatarURL()
    userinfo.name = user.username;
    userinfo.discrim = `#${user.discriminator}`;
    userinfo.id = user.id;
    userinfo.status = user.presence.status;
    userinfo.registered = moment.gmt(m.guild.members.fetch(user.id).user.createdAt);
    userinfo.joined = moment.gmt(m.guild.members.fetch(user.id).joinedAt);

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(user.tag, userinfo.avatar)
    .setThumbnail(userinfo.avatar)
    .addField(`Username`, userinfo.name, true)
    .addField(`Discriminator`, userinfo.discrim, true)
    .addField(`Status`, userinfo.status, true)
    .addField(`ID`, userinfo.id)
    .addField(`Registered`, userinfo.registered)
    .addField(`Joined`, userinfo.joined)

    return m.channel.send(embed);
}



});

bot.login("XXX")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.fetch` is an async function, so you need to use `await` or `.then`, you already have instance of a `User` with `let user = (m.mentions.users.first()) || m.author` so why not use that?

```js
userinfo.registered = moment.gmt(user.createdAt);
userinfo.joined = moment.gmt(user.joinedAt);
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!! So your solution solved the errors, but user.joinedAt was coming back undefined, i realised that should be member.joinedAt.